# django dynamic form initial attribute not honored

Tags: django, django-forms

i'm creating forms dynamically via this class:

```
    class dynform (forms.Form):

        def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):

            super(dynform,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                for i in args:
                    for k,v in i.iteritems():

                        self.fields[k] = eval(v)
```

i'm passing the fields as a dictionary like:

```
    {'Hand Hygiene Performed Before Patient Contact': 
             'forms.ChoiceField(choices=boolResponses,required=False,initial="No")'}
```

the boolReponses tuple has 'Yes','No','N/A' values, my problem is that my "initial = 'No'" is not honored in the web-page.

note: i also tried adding this to the form class:

```
   self.fields[k].initial='No'
```

but still wasn't honored

Comment: But these are strings. Why are you passing them like that? And where are they coming from?

Comment: the eval() instantiates them, i'm passing them via a queryset, i'm trying to allow users to define their document structure, and call it in the front end.

Comment: Are you really sure that this is a good idea, `eval` is typically *very* unsecure.

Comment: i understand your concern, i'm not taking the form field class expression directly from users, user selects 'text field' or 'choices field' , ...etc then it gets saved as a form field class expression, but i'm still with u on this so if you are ok to suggest an alternative, i'd be very thankful.

Comment: @adelelsayed: it is not only the fact that `eval(..)` can be "hacked", but for example you pass a variable `boolResponses` in your string, but if that one is not located where the `eval` takes place. It is not only insecure, it it is probably one of the seldom things that violates (close to) all design principles.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, if you are ok to suggest an alternative to the eval() scenario, i'd be very thankful.

Comment: Why not set initial values in the view?